# Ruby - reading from .csv and creating objects out of it

Tags: ruby, csv

I have .csv file with rows of which every row represents one call with certain duration, number etc. I need to create array of Call objects - every Call.new expects Hash of parameters, so it's easy - it just takes rows from CSV. But for some reason it doesn't work - when I invoke `Call.new(raw_call)` it's `nil`.
It's also impossible for me to see any output - I placed `puts` in various places in code (inside blocks etc) and it simply doesn't show anything. I obviously have another class - `Call`, which holds initialize for Call etc.

```
require 'csv'
class CSVCallParser
  attr_accessor :io

  def initialize(io)
    self.io = io
  end

  NAMES = {
    a: :date,
    b: :service,
    c: :phone_number,
    d: :duration,
    e: :unit,
    f: :cost
  }

  def run
    parse do |raw_call| 
    parse_call(raw_call)
    end
  end

  private

  def parse_call(raw_call) 
    NAMES.each_with_object({}) do |name, title, memo|
      memo[name] = raw_call[title.to_s]
    end
  end

  def parse(&block) 
    CSV.parse(io, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, &block)
  end

end

CSVCallParser.new(ARGV[0]).run
```

Small sample of my .csv file: headers and one row:

```
"a","b","c","d","e","f"
"01.09.2016 08:49","International","48627843111","0:29","","0,00"
```

Comment: can you provide a small sample of the csv file you are working with? So I can try to reproduce your code and see what's happening

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed a few things that isn't going as expected. In the `parse_call` method,

```
def parse_call(raw_call) 
  NAMES.each_with_object({}) do |name, title, memo|
    memo[name] = raw_call[title.to_s]
  end
end
```

I tried to print `name`, `title`, and `memo`. I expected to get `:a`, `:date`, and `{}`, but what I actually got was `[:a,:date]`,`{}`, and `nil`.

Also, `raw_call` headers are `:a,:b,:c...`, not `:date, :service...`, so you should be using `raw_call[name]`, and converting that to string will not help, since the key is a symbol in the `raw_call`.

So I modified the function to

```
def parse_call(raw_call) 
  NAMES.each_with_object({}) do |name_title, memo|
    memo[name_title[1]] = raw_call[name_title[0]]
  end
end
```

`name_title[1]` returns the title (`:date`, `:service`, etc)

`name_title[0]` returns the name (`:a`, `:b`, etc)

Also, in this method

```
def run
  parse do |raw_call| 
    parse_call(raw_call)
  end
end
```

You are not returning any results you get, so you are getting `nil`,

So, I changed it to

```
  def run
    res = []
    parse do |raw_call| 
      res << parse_call(raw_call)
    end
    res 
  end
```

Now, if I output the line

```
p CSVCallParser.new(File.read("file1.csv")).run
```

I get (I added two more lines to the csv sample)

```
[{:date=>"01.09.2016 08:49", :service=>"International", :phone_number=>"48627843111", :duration=>"0:29", :unit=>"", :cost=>"0,00"},
 {:date=>"02.09.2016 08:49", :service=>"International", :phone_number=>"48622454111", :duration=>"1:29", :unit=>"", :cost=>"0,00"}, 
 {:date=>"03.09.2016 08:49", :service=>"Domestic", :phone_number=>"48627843111", :duration=>"0:29", :unit=>"", :cost=>"0,00"}]
```

If you want to run this program from the terminal like so

```
ruby csv_call_parser.rb calls.csv
```

(In this case, `calls.csv` is passed in as an argument to `ARGV`)

You can do so by modifying the last line of the ruby file.

```
p CSVCallParser.new(File.read(ARGV[0])).run
```

This will also return the array with hashes like before.

Comment: Thank you very very much, your modifications are getting me closer to full understanding of a problem. There's one more thing, I wanted to run program like this: ruby csv_call_parser.rb calls.csv, so I can get my results like this: CSVCallParser.new(ARGV[0]).run or CSVCallParser.new(File.read(ARGV[0]).run, but none of this work

Comment: See my update. What I did seems to be similar to what you have in your comment, but I was able to print out the hash array to the terminal.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have no idea how you helped me! So the main problem was using name and title? Using them as name_title[0] and [1] made all the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
puts csv.map(&:to_h)
```

outputs:

```
[{a:1, b:1}, {a:2, b:2}]
```